# App crashing with SIGABRT in `once.h` on definition of `dispatch_once`

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm suddenly getting a `SIGABRT` in `dispatch_once` as shown in Xcode below.

No changes have been recently added that use `dispatch_once`.

> `dispatch_once(predicate, block);` **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

[image: SIGABRT in dispatch_once]

```
#if DISPATCH_ONCE_INLINE_FASTPATH
DISPATCH_INLINE DISPATCH_ALWAYS_INLINE DISPATCH_NONNULL_ALL DISPATCH_NOTHROW
DISPATCH_SWIFT3_UNAVAILABLE("Use lazily initialized globals instead")
void
_dispatch_once(dispatch_once_t *predicate,
        DISPATCH_NOESCAPE dispatch_block_t block)
{
    if (DISPATCH_EXPECT(*predicate, ~0l) != ~0l) {
        dispatch_once(predicate, block);
    } else {
        dispatch_compiler_barrier();
    }
    DISPATCH_COMPILER_CAN_ASSUME(*predicate == ~0l);
}
#undef dispatch_once
#define dispatch_once _dispatch_once
#endif
#endif // DISPATCH_ONCE_INLINE_FASTPATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this issue occurred when a Storyboard and Class files were added to the project, and automatically added to the main Target, but *not* added to the Target Membership of the secondary Target.

The issue only occurred in the iOS Simulator, using the Target we use specifically for the simulator.

The issue was not caught by the compiler due to no real references to the class. Instead, a stringly-typed reference to the Storyboard name was used to construct the view:

```
[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboardFileThatWasNotAddedToThisTarget" bundle:nil];
```

Fixed by adding the new files to the secondary Target:

[image: Add Target Membership to secondary Target]

Found issue by adding an Exception Breakpoint to the Xcode debugger.

Comment: This would be much less error prone if files were automatically added to the correct Target Membership for a project. Please duplicate my bug report: rdar://33034215 `Xcode should add per-project default Target Membership to git / source control`

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused, but no confirmed by logs or exception traces, by the use of **KeychainItemWrapper**, as recommended [here](https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641#gistcomment-57670). I dropped that old class and replaced it with the modern solution *SAMKeychain*.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `Realm` and the crash happens when I updated the `Xcode` but pod was not updated. Make sure you update your pods using,

```
pod repo update
pod update
```

If you get permission issue run with `sudo`.

From realm website,

> Realm model properties must have the @objc dynamic var attribute to
>   become accessors for the underlying database data. Note that if the
>   class is declared as @objcMembers (Swift 4 or later), the individual
>   properties can just be declared as dynamic var.